# .\Objects\Usart.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol HAL_NVIC_SetPriority (referred from stm32f4xx_hal.o)

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, keil

I am using uart and added uart files manually from keil/PACKS/Drivers/HALdrivers  folder but after compiling i am facing the following errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message:

```
Undefined symbol HAL_NVIC_SetPriority (referred from stm32f4xx_hal.o)
```

Is telling you that some code from the file `stm32F4xx_hal.c` uses the symbol `HAL_NVIC_SetPriorty` but the symbol `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority` is undefined.  It's undefined because you haven't added the source file where it is defined into your project.  If you search through all of the STM32F4 HAL Driver source code, you will find that `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority` is a function that is defined in `stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c`.  You need to add the file `stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c` into your project to provide the definition of `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority`.

Adding `stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c` should solve at least one of your errors.  But it may create new errors if `stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c` uses new undefined symbols.  You will have to iterate on this process.

1. Search the HAL Driver source code for the undefined symbol to find
   where it is defined.
2. Then add the source file containing the definition to your project.
3. Repeat for the next undefined symbol.